# psutil processes that are not running, or reused or are dead or zombie

Tags: python, process, psutil

What does psutil.process_iter() include? Since, its a cached instance, does it include only processes that are running at the time or it includes everything and leaves their present status to be user verified? My code:

```
for _process in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        new_proc = _process.as_dict(attrs=['cpu_times', 'name', 'pid', 'status'])
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        continue
```

What all status gets filtered here? And what all do I have to verify on my own?

Comment: thanks for the tag. It required 1500 reputation to add a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs for `psutil.process_iter()` say](http://psutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#psutil.process_iter):

> Return an iterator yielding a Process class instance for all **running**
>   processes on the local machine. Every instance is only created once and then cached into an internal table which is **updated every time an element is yielded.** <sub>emphasize is mine</sub>

where "running" is defined by [`.is_running()` method](http://psutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#psutil.Process.is_running) that returns `True` for zombie processes. `.is_running()` is safe to use even if the process is gone and its pid is reused.

My understanding is that `_process.is_running()` is true at the moment `psutil.process_iter()` yields it. In principle, before `_process.as_dict` returns with the info, several things may happen:

1. process may die -- become a zombie: `_process.is_running()` is true, `pid` and `status` are meaningful
2. it may be reaped  -- dead-dead: the process info is unavailable (`psutil.NoSuchProcess` exception) or outdated (if cached)
3. its pid may be reused -- some `_process` methods may return incorrectly the info for the *new* process. `.is_running()` uses several process attributes so it should detect the case when `pid` is reused.

Normally, OS doesn't reuse `pid` immediately therefore p.3 shouldn't occur frequently.

Comment: That is correct. The `Process` class is bound to a process via its PID. As such, that PID can disappear at any time or be reused [1]. That is why every time you deal with it you're supposed to do it in a try/except catching at least `NoSuchProcess` exception (which also includes `ZombieProcess`).
[1] it must be said that unless the `Process` instance is old the risk of incurring into PIDs being reused is very low or perhaps 0.

Answer (score 2):

`psutil.process_iter()` iterates over all the running processes in the system. `ZombieProcess` error is mostly observed in MacOS and workaround could be to handle it in the exception with `except psutil.ZombieProcess:`

```
for _process in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        new_proc = _process.as_dict(attrs=['cpu_times', 'name', 'pid', 'status'])
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        continue
    except psutil.ZombieProcess:
        continue
```